# iOS App Crashing Instantly After Opening It

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, crash, ios-simulator

I am testing my iOS app on my phone and when I try opening it, it instantly exits. App builds and works in simulator. Does anyone know what could be the cause?

I verified and checked that my provisioning profile + certificates are all valid and they are. Nothing has expired.

I believe the error may be coming from this step from the console logs:

```
error   13:45:10.855026 -0400   symptomsd   Can't get most elevated app state from dictionary {
    BKSApplicationStateExtensionKey = 0;
    SBApplicationStateDisplayIDKey = "com.capitalone.Jupiter";
    SBApplicationStateKey = 0;
    SBApplicationStateProcessIDKey = 991;
    SBApplicationStateRunningReasonsKey =     (
                {
            SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionIdentifierKey = Resume;
            SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionReasonKey = 10000;
        },
                {
            SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionIdentifierKey = UIApplicationLaunch;
            SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionReasonKey = 10000;
        }
    );
}
```

Full logs below.

Here are the logs from xcode:

```
default 13:45:10.348434 -0400   SpringBoard Bootstrapping com.My.Bundle.Id with intent foreground-interactive
default 13:45:10.348590 -0400   assertiond  Submitting new job for "com.My.Bundle.Id" on behalf of <BKProcess: 0x101c03a60; SpringBoard; com.apple.springboard; pid: 52; agency: SystemShell; visibility: foreground; task: running>
default 13:45:10.349683 -0400   assertiond  Submitted job with label: UIKitApplication:com.My.Bundle.Id[0xe595][62]
default 13:45:10.382109 -0400   SpringBoard [com.My.Bundle.Id] Bootstrap complete with label: UIKitApplication:com.My.Bundle.Id[0xe595][62]
default 13:45:10.382495 -0400   SpringBoard Adding: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x146b73c10; Jupiter (com.My.Bundle.Id); pid: 991>
default 13:45:10.384602 -0400   assertiond  Now tracking process <BKProcess: 0x101b07760; Jupiter; com.My.Bundle.Id; pid: 991; agency: Application; visibility: none; task: running; hostpid: 52> with host <BKProcess: 0x101c03a60; SpringBoard; com.apple.springboard; pid: 52; agency: SystemShell; visibility: foreground; task: running>
default 13:45:10.396434 -0400   mediaserverd    -CMSessionMgr- CMSessionMgrHandleApplicationStateChange: CMSession: Client com.My.Bundle.Id with pid '991' is now Foreground Running. Background entitlement: NO
default 13:45:10.401556 -0400   SpringBoard [com.My.Bundle.Id] Setting deactivation reasons to: 'systemAnimation' for reason: scene settings update - settings are eligible for deactivation reasons.
default 13:45:10.415638 -0400   SpringBoard Application process state changed for com.My.Bundle.Id: <SBApplicationProcessState: 0x28130de40; pid: 991; taskState: Running; visibility: Unknown>
default 13:45:10.433713 -0400   SpringBoard WIFI PICKER [com.My.Bundle.Id]: isProcessLaunch: 1,    isForegroundActivation: 1,     isForegroundDeactivation: 0
default 13:45:10.434940 -0400   symptomsd   991 com.My.Bundle.Id: ForegroundRunning (most elevated: ForegroundRunning)
default 13:45:10.435072 -0400   symptomsd   Entry, display name com.My.Bundle.Id uuid 5DF98506-8B88-381F-8E79-82FB0DA768FC pid 991 isFront 1
default 13:45:10.435420 -0400   symptomsd   Continue with bundle name com.My.Bundle.Id, is front 1
default 13:45:10.435464 -0400   symptomsd   com.My.Bundle.Id: Foreground: true
default 13:45:10.435746 -0400   symptomsd   Failed to find process for com.My.Bundle.Id
default 13:45:10.641383 -0400   SpringBoard [com.My.Bundle.Id] Setting deactivation reasons to: '(none)' for reason: updateAllScenesForBand - Assertion removed.
default 13:45:10.775095 -0400   backboardd  Connection added: IOHIDEventSystemConnection uuid:960FB53D-5C0A-47D5-8260-BB2E2A63D61B pid:991 process:Jupiter type:Passive entitlements:0x0 caller:BackBoardServices: <redacted> + 368 attributes:<CFBasicHash 0x10bd00b70 [0x102f00010]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x102b799f0 [0x20baeba30]>{contents = "pid"} = <CFNumber 0xc45bcab69880bc04 [0x20baeba30]>{value = +991, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
    1 : <CFString 0x102b48c20 [0x20baeba30]>{contents = "bundleID"} = <CFString 0x102b6c3f0 [0x20baeba30]>{contents = "com.My.Bundle.Id"}
    2 : <CFString 0x102b065e0 [0x20baeba30]>{contents = "HighFrequency"} = <CFBoolean 0x20baf1a10 [0x20baeba30]>{value = true}
}
 inactive:1
default 13:45:10.789855 -0400   backboardd  Connection removed: IOHIDEventSystemConnection uuid:960FB53D-5C0A-47D5-8260-BB2E2A63D61B pid:991 process:Jupiter type:Passive entitlements:0x0 caller:BackBoardServices: <redacted> + 368 attributes:<CFBasicHash 0x10bd00b70 [0x102f00010]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x102b799f0 [0x20baeba30]>{contents = "pid"} = <CFNumber 0xc45bcab69880bc04 [0x20baeba30]>{value = +991, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
    1 : <CFString 0x102b48c20 [0x20baeba30]>{contents = "bundleID"} = <CFString 0x102b6c3f0 [0x20baeba30]>{contents = "com.My.Bundle.Id"}
    2 : <CFString 0x102b065e0 [0x20baeba30]>{contents = "HighFrequency"} = <CFBoolean 0x20baf1a10 [0x20baeba30]>{value = true}
}
 inactive:0
default 13:45:10.791946 -0400   SpringBoard [com.My.Bundle.Id] Sending scene action [Logical Activate] through WorkspaceServer: 0x283139630
default 13:45:10.797970 -0400   SpringBoard [com.My.Bundle.Id] Sending scene action [SceneLifecycleEventOnly] through WorkspaceServer: 0x283139630
default 13:45:10.798522 -0400   SpringBoard [com.My.Bundle.Id] Sending scene action [SceneLifecycleEventOnly] through WorkspaceServer: 0x283139630
default 13:45:10.800563 -0400   SpringBoard Application process state changed for com.My.Bundle.Id: <SBApplicationProcessState: 0x281252bc0; pid: 991; taskState: Not Running; visibility: Unknown>
default 13:45:10.803944 -0400   SpringBoard Application process state changed for com.My.Bundle.Id: <SBApplicationProcessState: 0x2812536a0; pid: 991; taskState: Running; visibility: Foreground>
default 13:45:10.807589 -0400   backboardd  [BKEventFocusManager] Setting foreground application to: com.My.Bundle.Id (991)
default 13:45:10.854839 -0400   SpringBoard WIFI PICKER [com.My.Bundle.Id]: isProcessLaunch: 0,    isForegroundActivation: 0,     isForegroundDeactivation: 1
error   13:45:10.855026 -0400   symptomsd   Can't get most elevated app state from dictionary {
    BKSApplicationStateExtensionKey = 0;
    SBApplicationStateDisplayIDKey = "com.My.Bundle.Id";
    SBApplicationStateKey = 0;
    SBApplicationStateProcessIDKey = 991;
    SBApplicationStateRunningReasonsKey =     (
                {
            SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionIdentifierKey = Resume;
            SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionReasonKey = 10000;
        },
                {
            SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionIdentifierKey = UIApplicationLaunch;
            SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionReasonKey = 10000;
        }
    );
}
default 13:45:10.855086 -0400   symptomsd   991 com.My.Bundle.Id: Unknown (most elevated: Unknown)
default 13:45:10.855150 -0400   symptomsd   Entry, display name com.My.Bundle.Id uuid (null) pid 991 isFront 0
default 13:45:10.855393 -0400   symptomsd   Continue with bundle name com.My.Bundle.Id, is front 0
default 13:45:10.855456 -0400   symptomsd   com.My.Bundle.Id: Foreground: false
default 13:45:10.855519 -0400   symptomsd   Failed to find process for com.My.Bundle.Id
default 13:45:10.970118 -0400   SpringBoard Front display did change: <SBApplication: 0x282df9a40; com.My.Bundle.Id>
default 13:45:10.995763 -0400   SpringBoard [com.My.Bundle.Id] Will update scene - foregroundness changed to: Background
default 13:45:11.999866 -0400   assertiond  [SpringBoard:52] Attempting to acquire assertion for Jupiter:991: <BKProcessAssertion: 0x100d12ba0; "FBSceneSnapshotAction:com.My.Bundle.Id" (finishTask:180s); id:…FE83F1033A36>
default 13:45:11.000082 -0400   assertiond  [Jupiter:991] Add assertion: <BKProcessAssertion: 0x100d12ba0; id: 52-341DA9E7-EC57-4850-8882-FE83F1033A36; name: FBSceneSnapshotAction:com.My.Bundle.Id; state: active; reason: finishTask; duration: 180.0s> {
    owner = <BSProcessHandle: 0x101a0a550; SpringBoard:52; valid: YES>;
    flags = preventSuspend, preventThrottleDownUI, preventThrottleDownCPU, preventIdleSleep, preventSuspendOnSleep;
}
default 13:45:11.000215 -0400   assertiond  [Jupiter:991] Activate assertion: <BKProcessAssertion: 0x100d12ba0; "FBSceneSnapshotAction:com.My.Bundle.Id" (finishTask:180s); id:…FE83F1033A36>
default 13:45:11.015843 -0400   powerd  Process assertiond.62 Created SystemIsActive "Jupiter:991:52-341DA9E7-EC57-4850-8882-FE83F1033A36 [FBSceneSnapshotAction:com.My.Bundle.Id] [0x100d12ba0]" age:00:00:00  id:51539642211 [System: SysAct]
default 13:45:11.187081 -0400   assertiond  Server invalidated <BKProcessAssertion: 0x100d12ba0; "FBSceneSnapshotAction:com.My.Bundle.Id" (finishTask:180s); id:…FE83F1033A36>
default 13:45:11.187457 -0400   assertiond  Client relinquished <BKProcessAssertion: 0x100d12ba0; "FBSceneSnapshotAction:com.My.Bundle.Id" (finishTask:180s); id:…FE83F1033A36>
default 13:45:11.187934 -0400   assertiond  Process exited: <BKProcess: 0x101b07760; Jupiter; com.My.Bundle.Id; pid: 991; agency: Application; visibility: none; task: none; hostpid: 52>
default 13:45:11.188564 -0400   powerd  Process assertiond.62 Released SystemIsActive "Jupiter:991:52-341DA9E7-EC57-4850-8882-FE83F1033A36 [FBSceneSnapshotAction:com.My.Bundle.Id] [0x100d12ba0]" age:00:00:00  id:51539642211 [System: SysAct]
default 13:45:11.355578 -0400   SpringBoard <FBApplicationProcess: 0x146b73c10; Jupiter (com.My.Bundle.Id); pid: 991> assertiond says the process actually exited with context: <BKSProcessExitContext: 0x2810cbfc0; reason: crash>
default 13:45:11.356682 -0400   SpringBoard <FBApplicationProcess: 0x146b73c10; Jupiter (com.My.Bundle.Id); pid: 991> crashed.
default 13:45:11.357390 -0400   SpringBoard Removing: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x146b73c10; Jupiter (com.My.Bundle.Id); pid: 991>
default 13:45:11.358054 -0400   SpringBoard Process exited: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x146b73c10; Jupiter (com.My.Bundle.Id); pid: -1> -> <FBApplicationProcessExitContext: 0x281cffbd0; exitReason: crash; terminationReason: (none)> {
    stateAtExit = <FBProcessState: 0x281307fe0; pid: 991; taskState: Not Running; visibility: Unknown>;
}
default 13:45:11.359464 -0400   SpringBoard Application process state changed for com.My.Bundle.Id: (null)
default 13:45:11.375592 -0400   assertiond  Deleted job with label: UIKitApplication:com.My.Bundle.Id[0xe595][62]
default 13:45:11.375852 -0400   assertiond  [Jupiter:991] Deleted launchd job with label: UIKitApplication:com.My.Bundle.Id[0xe595][62]
default 13:45:11.377370 -0400   assertiond  Checking for deferred bootstrap request for com.My.Bundle.Id
default 13:45:11.394094 -0400   mediaserverd    -CMSessionMgr- CMSessionMgrHandleApplicationStateChange: CMSession: Client com.My.Bundle.Id with pid '991' is now Terminated. Background entitlement: NO
default 13:45:11.395671 -0400   SpringBoard WIFI PICKER [com.My.Bundle.Id]: isProcessLaunch: 0,    isForegroundActivation: 0,     isForegroundDeactivation: 0
default 13:45:11.397915 -0400   symptomsd   991 com.My.Bundle.Id: Terminated (most elevated: Terminated)
default 13:45:11.398135 -0400   symptomsd   Entry, display name com.My.Bundle.Id uuid (null) pid 991 isFront 0
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: If you don't mind sharing the solution, would appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a developer profile.

it seems some issue with bundle id and profile you are trying to run on device. A distribution profile is still a valid profile but it would launch the app. and close it out immediately.

```
  default 13:45:10.855519 -0400   symptomsd   Failed to find process for com.My.Bundle.Id
```

1) Go to Target -> Build Settings -> Code Signing Identity. Make sure it's set to Developer.

2) Change code signing Style to Manual (I recommend this step so as to make sure you manually specify the correct profile to be used in. You can keep automatic and it should select the profile for your bundle id)

3) Go to Target -> General. Manually select your right profile. Clean and Run after that.